# Convert selected dataframe column to another class

Tags: r, class, dataframe, apply, coercion

I would like to add a vector of character class to a dataframe without affecting the type of class of the other columns.
For example, the dataframe mtcars consists only of numeric types of columns and if I add an additional column like this,

```
m <- mtcars
col <- rownames(mtcars)
m <- data.frame(m, col)
```

then all the original numeric classes of columns are converted to character class. Why is this happening? Is there a way to avoid this? And let's say I don't mind converting each columns back to their respective classes after the addition of the column `col`, how would I do that?

[image]

Comment: What you are seeing might be happening if mtcars were a matrix but not if it is a dataframe.

Comment: Just to be clear; to determine the class of the dataframe `m` I use `apply(m,2,class)`. Applying this to `m` after adding `col` returns "character" for all the columns. Same results were returned after using `cbind()`. Could it be an issue of different settings of R?

Comment: According to `class(m)` both before and after the addition of `col` returns "data.frame".

Comment: Don't use `apply(m, 2, class)`, because `apply` coerces `m` to a matrix before applying the function. Since it's coerced to a matrix, all columns are coerced to character. i.e. This does _not_ reflect the classes of the columns of `m`, but rather the classes of the columns of `as.matrix(m)`. Use `sapply(m, class)`, or `str(m)`.

Comment: (This is a good example of why it's important to include all the code necessary to reproduce your issue/error.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Screenshot added

Comment: Here's a clue: Learn to use `str` on the objects. This would show you that using `apply` destroys class information about `m`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code shouldn't change the class of the pre-existing columns of `m`. As mentioned in the comments, your object is likely a matrix (which requires constant class for all columns), and not a dataframe (which doesn't have this requirement).

That said, if you want to change the class of a subset of columns (of a dataframe) in a batch, then you can do the following:

```
m[1:11] <- lapply(m[1:11], as.numeric)
```

Comment: I know it shouldn't and yet it does. I do `class(m)` and it returns as "data.frame" both pre- and post- addition of `col`.

Comment: I also tried your code and all the columns still stayed as "character".

Comment: @Wolfgang - See my comment on your question.

Comment: I wouldn't even suggest the `apply` version for this answer. `lapply` is more than sufficient.

Comment: @thelatemail - good point. I'd included `apply` for the matrix case (changing the class of _all_ columns), but it confuses the issue.